# How to modify the attributes of a single cell on a tableview

Tags: java, javafx

This is the first time I've had to work with JavaFX (and hopefully the last) so I don't exactly understand how everything works. I'll try to sum where I am briefly

1. I am trying to make my table highlight duplicate cells on a specific column
2. I need editable cells and no TableCell extensions I've come across work, I've been spending most of today trying to fix their bugs to no avail. I've given up on that approach.
3. I found TextFieldTableCell but that does not allow me to extend and override functions like updateItem. At this point I have no interest in re-implementing any of this functionality.

Currently what I do is the following:

```
CollectionName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("CollectionName"));
CollectionName.setCellFactory(EditingCell.<Item>forTableColumn(this)); //At the moment this just passes though TextFieldTableCell, the parameter is totally inconsequential
CollectionName.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Item, String> t) ->
{
    ((Item) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).setCollectionName(t.getNewValue());
    System.out.println("Set on edit commit");
    if(isDuplicateName(t.getNewValue()))
    {
        t.getTableView().getColumns().get(t.getTablePosition().getColumn()).getStyleClass().add("duplicate-cell");
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
    }
    else
    {
        t.getTableView().getColumns().get(t.getTablePosition().getColumn()).getStyleClass().remove("duplicate-cell");
        System.out.println("Not duplicate");
    }
});
```

This functions as intended but highlights the entire column. I need it to highlight only the specific cell. I wish there was a way to simply call myTable.getCell(x,y).getStyleClass().add("duplicate-cell") or something. I mean it is a table after all...

Comment: Not sure why you say you can't override `TextFieldTableCell.updateItem(...)`. That is not a `final` method. Just override the that method to add or remove the `duplicate-cell` style class. (The reason there's not `getCell(x,y)` method is that there might not *be* a cell for `(x,y)`, and whether there is or not depends on the state of the view (scrolling position, etc etc). Any logic should be based on the data, not on the view.)

Comment: I was explicitly stating the first parameter as a String where it needs to be T. When I change it to T it works. However, that creates other issues and I remember being here before like 3 hours ago. At the moment I'd rather just fix my current approach because it's the closest I've been yet.

Comment: Your current approach won't work. I have no idea what you mean by the parameter type. It would just be the same as the parameter type for the column.

Comment: "It wont work" is a good answer to this question. I'll continue working on the extended class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have it working, sort of. There's still some issues to work through like only being able to update one of the two duplicates, there's probably some callbacks I need to add for that but I'll deal with it on Monday or just scrap the feature altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to any problem involving changing the appearance of table cells based on certain state of the cell's item, and other data, is *always* to use a cell factory which returns a cell that updates its appearance accordingly.

The problem with the approach you are trying is that you are overlooking the fact that the table view reuses cells. For example, if the table contains a large amount of data and the user scrolls, new cells will not be created but cells that are scrolled out of view will be reused for the new items that scroll into view. Since you don't update the style of the cell when this happens, scrolling will make the wrong cells highlighted.

Here the logic is a little tricky as each cell essentially has to observe all values in the column (whether they are currently displayed or not). I think the easiest solution here is to independently maintain an `ObservableSet` that keeps a list of duplicate entries, and have the cell observe that. Here's an implementation. You can probably factor this out into a separate class for the cell factory (or something convenient) to make it more elegant and reusable.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class HighlightDuplicateTableCells extends Application {

    // create an observable list that fires events if the dataProperty of any elements change:

    private final ObservableList<Item> items = 
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new Observable[]{item.dataProperty()});

    // collection of strings that are duplicated in the data properties of all the items:

    private final ObservableSet<String> duplicateData = FXCollections.observableSet();

    private static final PseudoClass DUPLICATE_PC = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("duplicate");

    private final StringConverter<String> identityStringConverter = new StringConverter<String>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(String object) {
            return object;
        }

        @Override
        public String fromString(String string) {
            return string;
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // listener to maintain collection of duplicates:
        items.addListener((Change<? extends Item> change) -> updateDuplicateData());

        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setItems(items);

        TableColumn<Item, Number> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getId()));

        TableColumn<Item, String> dataColumn = new TableColumn<>("Data");
        dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty());

        dataColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> {

            TextFieldTableCell<Item, String> cell = new TextFieldTableCell<Item, String>(identityStringConverter) {

                // boolean binding that indicates if the current item is contained in the duplicateData set:
                private BooleanBinding duplicate = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                        () -> duplicateData.contains(getItem()),
                        duplicateData, itemProperty());

                // anonymous constructor just updates CSS pseudoclass if above binding changes:
                {
                    duplicate.addListener((obs, wasDuplicate, isNowDuplicate) -> 
                        pseudoClassStateChanged(DUPLICATE_PC, isNowDuplicate));
                }
            };

            return cell ;
        });

        table.getColumns().add(idColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(dataColumn);

        // note best to minimize changes to items.
        // creating a temp list and using items.setAll(...) achieves this:

        List<Item> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 70; i++) {
            char c = (char)('@' + (i % 60));
            String data = Character.toString(c) ;
            tmp.add(new Item(i, data));
        }

        items.setAll(tmp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("duplicate-cell-example.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateDuplicateData() {

        // TODO: may not be most efficient implementation

        // all data:
        List<String> data = items.stream().map(Item::getData).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // unique data:
        Set<String> uniqueData = new HashSet<>(data);
        // remove unique values from data:
        uniqueData.forEach(data::remove);
        // remaining values are duplicates: replace contents of duplicateData with these:
        duplicateData.clear();
        duplicateData.addAll(data);
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final int id ;
        private final StringProperty data = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(int id, String data) {
            this.id = id ;
            setData(data);
        }

        public final StringProperty dataProperty() {
            return this.data;
        }


        public final String getData() {
            return this.dataProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setData(final String data) {
            this.dataProperty().set(data);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id ;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the duplicate-cell-example.css:

```
.table-cell:duplicate {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background ;
    -fx-background: red ;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising and gives a good explanation of why my question was using a bad approach. I don't have the brainpower to integrate this into my code right now so I'll get back to you on Monday. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically James_D's approach, but it improves the time required for updates from `Ω(n²)` worst case (`n` = list size) to `O(m)` where `m` is the number of changes (`1` for updates of a property; the number of elements added/removed on a list update).

This performance is achieved by storing the number of occurances in a `ObservableMap<String, Integer>`:

```
private final ObservableMap<String, Integer> valueOccuranceCounts = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

private final ChangeListener<String> changeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    valueOccuranceCounts.computeIfPresent(oldValue, REMOVE_UPDATER);
    valueOccuranceCounts.merge(newValue, 1, ADD_MERGER);
};

private static final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> ADD_MERGER = (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue + 1;
private static final BiFunction<String, Integer, Integer> REMOVE_UPDATER = (key, value) -> {
    int newCount = value - 1;
    // remove mapping, if the value would become 0
    return newCount == 0 ? null : newCount;
};

private final ListChangeListener<Item> listChangeListener = (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            for (Item r : c.getRemoved()) {
                // decrease count and remove listener
                this.valueOccuranceCounts.computeIfPresent(r.getData(), REMOVE_UPDATER);
                r.dataProperty().removeListener(this.changeListener);
            }
        }
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            for (Item a : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                // increase count and add listener
                this.valueOccuranceCounts.merge(a.getData(), 1, ADD_MERGER);
                a.dataProperty().addListener(this.changeListener);
            }
        }
    }
};

private final ObservableList<Item> items;

{
    items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    items.addListener(listChangeListener);
}

private static final PseudoClass DUPLICATE = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("duplicate");
private static final String FIRST_COLUMN_CLASS = "first-column";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>(items);
//    tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn<Item, String> column = new TableColumn<>("data");
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty());

    column.setCellFactory(col -> new TextFieldTableCell<Item, String>() {

        // boolean binding that indicates if the current item is contained in the duplicateData set:
        private final BooleanBinding duplicate = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                () -> valueOccuranceCounts.getOrDefault(getItem(), 1) >= 2,
                valueOccuranceCounts, itemProperty());

        // anonymous constructor just updates CSS pseudoclass if above binding changes:
        {
            duplicate.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)
                    -> pseudoClassStateChanged(DUPLICATE, newValue));
        }
    });

    TableColumn<Item, Number> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("id");
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getId()));

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(idColumn, column);
    tableView.getColumns().addListener((Observable observable) -> {
        // keep style class marking the cells of the column as
        // belonging to the first column up to date 
        if (tableView.getColumns().get(0) == column) {
            if (!column.getStyleClass().contains(FIRST_COLUMN_CLASS)) {
                column.getStyleClass().add(FIRST_COLUMN_CLASS);
            }
        } else {
            column.getStyleClass().remove(FIRST_COLUMN_CLASS);
        }
    });

    // note best to minimize changes to items.
    // creating a temp list and using items.setAll(...) achieves this:
    final int count = 70;
    List<Item> tmp = Arrays.asList(new Item[count]);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        tmp.set(i, new Item(Integer.toString(i % 60)));
    }

    items.setAll(tmp);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static class Item {

    private static int counter = 0;

    private final StringProperty data;
    private final int id = counter++;

    public Item(String data) {
        this.data = new SimpleStringProperty(data);
    }

    public final StringProperty dataProperty() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public final String getData() {
        return this.dataProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setData(final String data) {
        this.dataProperty().set(data);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id ;
    }

}
```

**style.css**

```css
.table-row-cell:filled .table-cell:duplicate {
    -fx-background: yellow;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-table-cell-border-color, -fx-background;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled .table-cell:duplicate:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-background;
}

/* keep use the same background colors normally used for focused table rows */
.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused .table-cell:duplicate {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background, -fx-cell-focus-inner-border, -fx-background;
    /* frame only at top & bottom sides */
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 0, 2 0 2 0;
}

.table-view:focused .table-row-cell:filled:focused .table-cell.first-column:duplicate {
    /* frame only for top, left and bottom sides*/
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1 0 1 1, 2 0 2 2;
}

.table-row-cell:filled .table-cell:duplicate:selected,
.table-row-cell:filled:selected .table-cell:duplicate {
    -fx-background: turquoise;
}
```

Note that some parts (creating & filling the table, creating the column) are copied from @James_D's answer, since it's simply best practice to do it this way.